# Flutter-during navigation want text variable is returning null(want to prioritize the function in navigation during elevated Button)

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I am sending an image to API and I want to show Snackbar to display if image is uploaded or not. 
I have defined text variable in class. And then from API response I am changing that variable but during Elevated button navigation value of text is changed but it is showing that is previously assigned.

This my f

```
Future CreateAuditAPI(String userId, String warehouseId, String base64IMG, String description) async{

  final Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://firebase.google.com/" );/*sample url for getting response I know it wil not work*/
  
  CreateAudit obj = CreateAudit(
      userID: userId,
      warehouseID: warehouseId,
      description: [description],
      imagedata: [base64IMG]
  );
  var d = jsonEncode(obj);
  print("printing data before passing");
  print(d);
  try {
    print("printing in try");
    final http.Response response = await client.post(uri,
        headers: headers, body: d);
    
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if (jsonResponse["status"] == 200) {
      text = jsonResponse["message"];
      return jsonResponse["data"];
      


    } else {
      text = "Something Went Wrong";
      throw Exception(jsonResponse["msg"]);

    }
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
   


  }




}
```

and the displaying of Snackbar is going here

```
class DisplayScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  /*DisplayScreen({super.key, required this.imagePath});*/
  String imagePath;
  String warehouseid ;
  DisplayScreen(this.imagePath, this.warehouseid);


  @override
  State<DisplayScreen> createState() => _DisplayScreenState();
}


class _DisplayScreenState extends State<DisplayScreen> {
  String? dropdownBuldingtype = '';
  
   String? _imagData;
   String? userID;

  String? text='Uploaded Successfully';





  Future<String> getExifFromFile() async {
    if (File(widget.imagePath) == null) {
      return "";
    }

   
    final fileBytes = File(widget.imagePath)!.readAsBytesSync();
    final data = await readExifFromBytes(fileBytes);

    if (data.isEmpty) {
      print("No EXIF information found");
      return "";
    }

    final datetime = data['EXIF DateTimeOriginal']?.toString();
    if (datetime == null) {
      print("datetime information not found");
      return "";
    }
    String? datetime1;

    
    datetime1 = datetime;
    
    print(widget.imagePath);
    File imagefile = File(widget.imagePath); //convert Path to File
    Uint8List imagebytes = await imagefile.readAsBytes(); //convert to bytes
    _imagData = base64.encode(imagebytes); //convert bytes to base64 string




    


    return datetime1;
  }
  Future CreateAuditAPI(String userId, String warehouseId, String base64IMG, String description) async{
    
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://firebase.google.com/" );
    print('insidewarehouse');
    print(uri);
    CreateAudit obj = CreateAudit(
        userID: userId,
        warehouseID: warehouseId,
        description: [description],
        imagedata: [base64IMG]
    );
    var d = jsonEncode(obj);
    print("printing data before passing");
    print(d);
    try {
      print("printing in try");
      final http.Response response = await client.post(uri,
          headers: headers, body: d);
      
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (jsonResponse["status"] == 200) {
        text = jsonResponse["message"];
        return jsonResponse["data"];


      } else {
        text = 'Something Went Wrong';
        throw Exception(jsonResponse["msg"]);

      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
      
    }




  }
  void getuserid() async{
    SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    userID =  _prefs.getString("userid");
  }
  TextEditingController description = TextEditingController();


  final client = http.Client();

  final headers ={
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  };
  /*var data;*/
@override
  void initState() {
  getuserid();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("attal======>"+widget.imagePath);
    /*data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
    // dropdownBuldingtype = data["buidlingtype"];
    print(data);*/

    getExifFromFile();
    getuserid();
    print("atal");

    print(widget.imagePath);
    /*String? warehouseID= data["warehouseid"].toString();
    print(warehouseID);*/

    final size = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size;
    final String _description = description.text;
    String? warehouseID = widget.warehouseid;
    print('warehiii');
    print(warehouseID);
    print('useriiiiiii');
    print(userID);




    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        leading: IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red, size: 50,), padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0), onPressed: () {Navigator.pop(context); },),
        actions:  [IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.check, color: Colors.green, size: 50,), padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
              actions: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [

                        IconButton(onPressed: (){
                          Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
                        }, icon: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.red,) )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width*0.07),
                      child: Text('Description : ', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width*0.07),
                      child: TextFormField(

                        controller: description,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2)),
                          enabledBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1 ),),
                        ),


                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: size.height*0.05,),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width*0.07),
                      child: Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('More Image'),style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.8),

                          ),),
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){CreateAuditAPI(userID!,warehouseID,_imagData!,description.text);
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$text"),action: SnackBarAction(label: 'OK',onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },),));
                            Navigator.pop(context);




                            

                          },



                            child: Text('Upload'), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.8),


                            ),)
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );},)],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      /*appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Display the Picture')),*/
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: SizedBox.expand(child: Image.file(File(widget.imagePath),



      )),






    );
  }


}
```

this is the issue.......

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){CreateAuditAPI(userID!,warehouseID,_imagData!,description.text);
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("$text"),action: SnackBarAction(label: 'OK',onPressed: (){
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },),));
  Navigator.pop(context);




},



  child: Text('Upload'), style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.8),


  ),)
```

it is calling API on the console it is uploading but in Snackbar it is not assigning the new value to text variable. Elevated Button is calling function of create Audit but it doing the Create Audit and Showing snackbar at the same time and not give the updated value of text to the  Snackbar.

I have tried removing sncakbar from the elevated button and putting Snackbar in CreateAuditAPI function but it is not calling the snackbar.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem that there is no waiting for the request as its handled as sync
you should await for the api request

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
await CreateAuditAPI(userID!,warehouseID,_imagData!,description.text);
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:Text("$text"),action: SnackBarAction(label: 'OK',onPressed: (){  Navigator.pop(context);
  },),));
  Navigator.pop(context);
},
```

Comment: it is still returning the previous text variable value.